# Problems updating El Capitan to High Sierra using bootable USB

Tags: upgrade, high-sierra

I'm running into a series of issues while attempting to install High Sierra on a mid-2013 Mac Pro currently running El Capitan.

Both when trying to update using the standard installer, and when booting from a USB installer created following the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372), I run into the same issue:

Midway through the install, a dialog appears stating that "macOS could not be installed on your computer An error occurred while verifying firmware."

When I restart from this dialog, a new one appears after restart stating that "The path /System/Installation/Packages/OSInstall.mpkg appears to be missing or damaged."

When I attempt to search for OSInstall.mpkg from the terminal in recovery mode, the following command:

```
find / -name OSInstall.mpkg
```

yields this response:

```
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
```

So I don't appear to have an option to copy the install media to the expected directory as some users appear to have done.

I see that this is a problem other users have encountered, but most seem to have succeeded by installing from USB, which is failing in my case. What's the recommended course of action from here?

Comment: Update: just worked partway through the issue with Apple support. What we wound up doing was to boot using Command+R to access the Disk Utility and wipe the drive, and then to reboot using Command+Option+R to boot into Internet Recovery, and download a working copy of an older OS (In this instance, Mavericks), and then upgrade to Sierra from there using the link provided [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208202). For now, on their advice, I'm holding off on upgrading to High Sierra.